# Comparing int with long and others

Tags: c, int, comparison, long-integer

I am wondering if things like this :

```
int a = ...;
long b = ...;

if (a < b)
     doSomethings();
```

always works (excepted for unsigned)

I just tested with a few values, but I want to be sure. I assume `a` is cast to long in the comparison, what about others type ?

Comment: What types? You need to be specific, also explain a use case for the posted code.

Comment: You may want to be explicit about signedness of the types.

Comment: You might want to learn more about the [implicit conversions in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: What do you mean by "except for unsigned"? There's no `unsigned` in the code.

Comment: Yes, because that won't work all the time. I read somewhere that in case of mixed signed / unsigned, the signed became unsigned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int/long` compare always works.  The 2 operands are converted to a common type, in this case `long` and all `int` can be converted to `long` with no problems.

```
int ii = ...;
long ll = ...;
if (ii < ll)
   doSomethings();
```

`unsigned/long` compare always works if `long` ranges exceeds `unsigned`.  If `unsigned` range was `[0...65535]` and `long` was `[-2G...2G-1]`, then the operands are converted to `long` and all `unsigned` can be converted to `long` with no problems.

```
unsigned uu16 = ...;
long ll32 = ...;
if (uu16 < ll32)
   doSomethings();
```

`unsigned/long` compare has trouble when `long` ranges does not exceed `unsigned`.  If `unsigned` range was `[0...4G-1]` and `long` was `[-2G...2G-1]`, then the operands are converted to `long`, a common type that does not encompass both ranges and problems ensue.

```
unsigned uu32 = ...;
long ll32 = ...;

// problems
if (uu32 < ll32)  
   doSomethings();

// corrected solution
if (uu32 <= LONG_MAX && uu32 < ll32)  
   doSomethings();

// wrong solution
if (ll32 < 0 || uu32 < ll32)  
   doSomethings();
```

If type `long long` includes all the range of `unsigned`, code could use do the compare with at least `long long` width.

```
unsigned uu;
long ll;
#if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
  if (uu < ll)  
#if LLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
  if (uu < ll*1LL)  
#else 
  if (uu32 <= LONG_MAX && uu32 < ll32)  
  // if (ll < 0 || uu < ll)  
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

In this condition

```
if (a < b)
```

an object of type `int` is always converted to the type `long` provided that one of the operands has type `long` because type `long` has higher rank than type `int`.

As for other types then according to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the **usual arithmetic
>   conversions** are performed.

It means that after the integer promotion an operand with a lower rank is converted to the type of the other operand.