# Is comparing a short to a long an implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

From what I understand, comparing two different types, including a `short` and a `long` will still cause a conversion. I ***believe*** that a `short` will be promoted to an `int`. However, I can't seem to find a direct answer on comparing a `short` to a `long`.

For example:

Is it improper to compare a `Uint32` to a `Uint8`.

Is it improper to add a `Uint32` to a `Uint8`?

Uint32/Uint8 are shorthand typedefs in SDL for `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`, respectively.

EDIT:
I suppose I should be a bit more explicit on my overall question. I'm really wondering whether or not comparing or evaluating with two different types of `int`s, that are the same signage (in the example case, `unsigned`), but differ in the **SIZE** (`uint8_t` and `uint32_t`), is an improper thing to do.

Perhaps it is improper due to a implicit conversion. Perhaps it is improper because of a performance issue other than conversion. Maybe it is frowned upon because of some sort of readability issue I am unaware of.

In the comments two similar questions were linked, however they are comparing an `int` to a `long`. Which I believe is very similar, but doesn't an `int` just take the form of whichever version is needed (`uint8_t`, `sint16_t`, etc.)?

Comment: _"If the operands has arithmetic or enumeration type (scoped or unscoped), usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands following the rules for arithmetic operators."_ source and follow the links: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

Comment: Comparison has the same [Usual Arithmetic Conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) as any other arithmetic operations.

Comment: C != C++. Please only tag with one of the languages, unless both really are actually relevant. What are `Uint32` and `Uint8`? They aren't standard types in C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the general rules for comparing different data types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636793/what-are-the-general-rules-for-comparing-different-data-types-in-c)

Comment: or dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568748/comparing-int-with-long-and-others

Comment: or dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010330/c-comparison-char-and-int

Comment: @4386427 All your dupe suggestions are tagged with C and therefore none of them are dupes.

Comment: Apologies to @tambre, I have not asked a question before. I fixed it as soon as I saw your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Comparing integers of different types, but same sign-age is always OK and well defined and will provide the expected arithmetic compare.

Comment: @NirFriedman When I posted the dups the question was tagged C but if you search for c++ dups you'll probably find just as many

Comment: @4386427 Right, and now it's not, which is why I drew attention to that point. You should also remove your close vote; it's not likely to get closed anyhow but it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question is answered with this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic under the subsection 'Conversions'.

> Otherwise, the operand has integer type (because bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and unscoped enumeration were promoted at this point) and integral conversions are applied to produce the common type, as follows:
>
> If both operands are signed or both are unsigned, the operand with lesser conversion rank is converted to the operand with the greater integer conversion rank

So the overall answer to my question is, **Yes, there is a conversion.** And from what I can tell, **there are no issues with comparing two `unsigned int` types, as long as you don't compared `signed` and `unsigned`.**

Comment: That's C, not C++, and thus cannot (by itself) be regarded as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you @NirFriedman I will update the answer accordingly. However, as far as I know, I cannot close this question as answered for two days unless someone else posts an answer.