# arithmetic of long int in c

Tags: c, integer, comparison, long-integer

I have the following source compiled in Linux 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64,g++ version 4.8.5

Case1:

```
printf("INT_MAX=(%d) , INT_MIN=(%d) \n",INT_MAX,INT_MIN);
int ix= 500  ;
long int lx1=0,lx2=0;
lx1=2147483647 + 10 ;
lx2=2100000000 ;
if( ix < (lx1-lx2) )
    printf("ix is not bigger \n");
else
    printf("ix is bigger \n");
```

compiled with warning :

```
warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
lx1=2147483647 + 10 ;
```

and output :

```
INT_MAX=(2147483647) , INT_MIN=(-2147483648) 
ix is bigger
```

and the following source Case2 :

```
printf("INT_MAX=(%d) , INT_MIN=(%d) \n",INT_MAX,INT_MIN);
int ix= 500  ;
long int lx1=0,lx2=0;
lx1=2200000000 + 10 ;
lx2=2100000000 ;
if( ix < (lx1-lx2) )
    printf("ix is not bigger \n");
else
    printf("ix is bigger \n");
```

compiled without warning and the output :

```
INT_MAX=(2147483647) , INT_MIN=(-2147483648) 
ix is not bigger
```

My question :  Why Case1 output can be wrong ? lx1 and lx2 both long int, in this box it is size 8 bytes , how come 2200000000 is fine but 2147483647 is not for lx1 ?!

[Comparing int with long and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568748/comparing-int-with-long-and-others)
is referd , still can not figure it out .

Comment: Just to be clear you know that `INT_MAX=(2147483647)` and you still try `lx1=2200000000 + 10 ;`? Then please elaborate what you thoughts are, what you expect, what types you assume are involved.

Comment: @Yunnosch isn't that perfectly fine foe a `long int`?

Comment: use the `L` suffix to tell the compiler that your int should be a long value `2147483647 + 10` => `2147483647L + 10L `

Comment: @Gerhardh You got me there. I admit that I had a mismatch of int and long int. But OPs code goes on to use int.... So my question kind of still makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation of `2147483647 + 10` happens with `int` datatypes, because both values fit into an `int`. The result overflows and then the result will be extended to a `long`, but that's too late.
Suffix the number with an `l` to make it a `long`: `2147483647l + 10`.

`2200000000` is too big for an `int`, therefore it is a `long`, so the additon works as expected.

https://ideone.com/ClJI8F

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `2147483647` is of type `int`, not long. So the calculation `2147483647 + 10` overflows and behaviour is *undefined*. The usual arithmetic conversions convert each operand to

- `int`
- or if not representable in `int` to the type of the operand having greater rank, and signed is converted to unsigned if of equal rank!

Since both operands are `int`s the addition happens with `int`.

Since `2200000000` does not fit 32-bit `int` it will be `long` or `long long` or (**unsigned int** if C89).

---

Always use a suffix for the integer constants when the size actually matter: `l` for longs, `u` for unsigned -- and `ll` for long long int; these can be coupled and are case sensitive so you can use `LL` for it to stand out from the others.

Finally, notice that `long int` need not be able to hold numbers greater than `2147483647` either, use `long long int` for that.

---

P.S. C89 did not have a `long long int` type at all, so in C89 vs C99+ the behaviour of the following would be different from each other if used as a constant expression on "`long` is 32-bit" machine!

```
-1 < 2147483647 + 10
```

It could result in 0 in C89 on 32-bit machine, and 1 in C99+ always.