# Comparing an int64_t value with another uint32_t value

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
 int64_t a = -1;
 uint32_t b = -1;

 bool c = a > b;
 std:: cout << c << std::endl;
 
 return 0;
}
```

My understanding is `b` which is a smaller type will be converted to the bigger type of `a` (unit32 to int64):

[Comparing int with long and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568748/comparing-int-with-long-and-others)

Then `a` which is a signed value will be turned to an unsigned value:

[Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Essentially our comparison will be turned into:

```
18446744073709551615 > 4294967295
```

But my `c` result is `false`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Essentially the comparison will be turned into `-1 > 4294967295`.

Comment: but looking at `a` as an unsigned number isn't `-1`. its `18446744073709551615`, isn't a signed value supposed to turn into unsigned if the other value is also unsigned?

Comment: `b` is not `18446744073709551615` (that's way too big to fit into a 32-bit unsigned int), it's `4294967295`.

Comment: @Eljay `a` is that value not `b`.

Comment: Have you tried this in [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/a5cb9a52) to see what happens?

Comment: The value of `a` is -1. The value of `b` is 
4294967295. The common type will be `std::int64_t` so your comparison between two `std::int64_t` comparing `-1 > 4294967295 ` which is `false`. You may be assuming the common type will be unsigned, but that is not accurate because `int64_t` can fully represent the range of values represented by `uint32_t`.

Comment: [Promotion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `int64_t a` and `uint32_t b`, in `a > b`, `b` will be **zero**-extended to 64 bits (remember, it's unsigned, so it's really `4294967295` and not `-1`), and then a comparison is performed. The relevant comparison is that `-1 > 4294967295` is false.

Relevant bits of [the C++ standard](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) are under "6.8.4 Integer conversion rank [conv.rank]", "The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with a
smaller width." and "The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.", under "7.4 Usual arithmetic conversions [expr.arith.conv]", "Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of
the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall
be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type." and under "7.6.9 Relational operators [expr.rel]", "The usual arithmetic conversions (7.4) are performed on operands of arithmetic or enumeration type."

Comment: But the second link above says `When comparing signed with unsigned, the compiler converts the signed value to unsigned`, isn't `a` supposed become unsigned?

Comment: @Dan That was in reference to an `int` and an `unsigned int`. You have a `long` and an `unsigned int`. This part of the answer applies to you instead: "Otherwise, if one operand is a long int and the other unsigned int, then if a long int can represent all the values of an unsigned int, the unsigned int shall be converted to a long int; otherwise both operands shall be converted to unsigned long int."

Comment: @AlexReynolds The expression `-1L > 0U` is false. If `a` became unsigned, wouldn't that be true instead?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That comparison is `false` if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(unsigned)`. This distinction is bypassed by the question because it uses fixed width integers instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point; I was indeed assuming the AMD64 SysV ABI.